# Is this a valid construction using the the perfect infinitive

Tags: infinitives, perfect-aspect

Is it correct to say " In order to have been". I understand that without context  the general meaning may be difficult to interpret, but could this even be used as a valid construction with the perfect infinitive?

Comment: It's fine. An example might be _In order to have been in Paris that day, she would have needed to travel by Eurostar_

Comment: @BillJ Isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: @Rathony What do you mean?

Comment: @BillJ I mean "In order to be in Paris" could be enough to get the meaning across.

Comment: @Rathony No, better to use a full sentence.

Comment: @Rathony *In order to be in Paris* would be used for a general rule and would take the enduring present in the main clause (*she needs to travel by Eurostar*) or the hypothetical (*she would need to travel by Eurostar*).  It could also be used for a future event certain, in which case the future (*she will need to travel by Eurostar*) or the future perfect (*she will have needed to travel by Eurostar*) would appear in the main clause.  *In order to have been in Paris* talks about a past event.  This ignores the complication of present narrative of past actions.

Comment: @deadrat In order to have gone to Harvard, he studied very hard. In order to have gone to Harvard, he should have studied harder. How do these two sentences sound?

Comment: @Rathony The first sounds a bit odd.  I think the present perfect (covering the attendance at any time in the past up to the present) clashes with the simple past.  The second moves in the hypothetical -- he might not have gone to Harvard -- and it sounds fine to me.  *He must have studied very hard* works if he actually went to Harvard.

Answer (score 0):

This use is absolutely usable and, in fact, probably the clearest way you could express your self in sentences like "In order to have been a suspect, she would have had to have been in the same area as the body was found."